# Maintaining an original cart quote in session and overwritting the current modified one, in Magento

Tags: magento, session, checkout, quote

The checkout process that I am currently working on a magento shop is as follows:

- step 1 - I simulate the order by sending some data to a custom api , and with the response received from that api, I change the current cart quote by changing some products qty,prices adding new free products...etc... so  major changes to the quote items are done
- step 2 - after I update the current quote based on the response received from api , I show the customer the new quote items. Also modifications to the item totals and subtotal are made as well
- step 3 (final step) - I make the actual order, sending again data to that api. The order after the quote is updated based again on response received from api, is also saved in magento.

All of the above steps happen in the checkout process page, and all 3 are mandatory.

My problem is that for the last step of the checkout process, i would need the original cart quote data, not the one modified after the simulation process.

I tried to save the original quote in session, but received an error when trying to serialize it: "Serialization of 'Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element' is not allowed"

I've also tried to save the result from $cart->getData() in session, which worked, but did not manage to re-import it to cart.

Any suggestions on how should I save the original cart quote and somehow re-import it?

Comment: "I've also tried to save the result from $cart->getData() in session, which worked, but did not manage to re-import it to cart."  - by this line i mean that i'm looking for some importFromArray function or something, if magento has any.  I could empty the cart, and parse the original getData() array and add each item from that array to cart, but was wondering if there isn't a simpler solution